# How to verify Android id token on App Engine backend

Tags: android, google-app-engine, authentication, google-oauth

my goal is to build simple app engine back end for my android app. Purpose of this back end is just to verify android clients calls ,and provide password which will be used for further https comunication with my servers.
So i started ccording to this http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/01/verifying-back-end-calls-from-android.html article.
Client side looks like:

```
GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(MainActivityy.this, "my.email@gmail.com", "audience:server:client_id:my_Client_ID_for_web_applications.apps.googleusercontent.com");
```

this method returns token which looks like this:

```
eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6ImFiMWIyZTllNGU2NGE0MmIzM2U3YjMxMDQwNzUyMzIxYmVlMmJkYmEifQ.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.oN5ncz6MEAZBW8NXDhc4O-Y82C2mma675lbw9ZZA-1bs8zM9FKQG1K97PfNfxJFImiPMY8UYIjhqDIkHpErjaV0KDJpLv8NkmsdADOFjt5eQkFGWf92fufL7QEIkWqLL1fKxG7f8-OR59O5AOAVchdgtqDt4DhEH7oHfAZqf3wU
```

and now i want to authentificate this token on backend. So i created new Web Application Project using Google plugin for eclpise. It generates some sample project. To this project i add Checker class from article which i mentioned above. looks like this:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleIdToken;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleIdTokenVerifier;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory;

public class Checker {

private final List mClientIDs;
private final String mAudience;
private final GoogleIdTokenVerifier mVerifier;
private final JsonFactory mJFactory;
private String mProblem = "Verification failed. (Time-out?)";

private  Logger log ;

public Checker(String[] clientIDs, String audience) {
    mClientIDs = Arrays.asList(clientIDs);
    mAudience = audience;
    NetHttpTransport transport = new NetHttpTransport();
    mJFactory = new GsonFactory();
    mVerifier = new GoogleIdTokenVerifier(transport, mJFactory);
   log = Logger.getLogger(Checker.class.getName()); 
   log.severe("CHECKER CRETAED");
}

public GoogleIdToken.Payload check(String tokenString) {
    GoogleIdToken.Payload payload = null;
    log.severe("CHECK START");
    try {
        log.severe("CHECK 1");
        GoogleIdToken token = GoogleIdToken.parse(mJFactory, tokenString);
        log.severe("CHECK 2");
        if (mVerifier.verify(token)) {
            log.severe("CHECK 3");
            GoogleIdToken.Payload tempPayload = token.getPayload();
            log.severe("CHECK4");
            if (!tempPayload.getAudience().equals(mAudience)){
                mProblem = "Audience mismatch";
                log.severe("Audience mismatch");
            }
            else if (!mClientIDs.contains(tempPayload.getIssuee())){
                mProblem = "Client ID mismatch";
                log.severe("Client ID mismatch");
            }
            else{
                payload = tempPayload;
                log.severe(payload.getEmail().toString());
                log.severe("CHECK 5");
            }
        }
    } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
        log.severe("Security issue: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        mProblem = "Security issue: " + e.getLocalizedMessage();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.severe("Network problem: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        mProblem = "Network problem: " + e.getLocalizedMessage();
    }
    log.severe("CHECK END");
    return payload;
}

public String problem() {
    return mProblem;
}
```

}

and now i do something like this to authentify token provided by android client.

```
String [] clinetidS  = new String [] {"xxxxxxxxxxxxx-plqjav9ih8e80btegic84bg2r9q7c02.apps.googleusercontent.com"};  //Client ID for installed applications
Checker checker = new Checker(clinetidS, "my_project_at_appspot.appspot.com");  
   checker.check("eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6ImFiMWIyZTllNGU2NGE0MmIzM2U3YjMxMDQwNzUyMzIxYmVlMmJkYmEifQ.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.oN5ncz6MEAZBW8NXDhc4O-Y82C2mma675lbw9ZZA-1bs8zM9FKQG1K97PfNfxJFImiPMY8UYIjhqDIkHpErjaV0KDJpLv8NkmsdADOFjt5eQkFGWf92fufL7QEIkWqLL1fKxG7f8-OR59O5AOAVchdgtqDt4DhEH7oHfAZqf3wU");
```

and now problem is that Checker class never pass this check:

```
if (mVerifier.verify(token))
```

is there some way how to check android token online?? any ideas??
or where can be problem??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can always check the token interactively by using curl to look at

curl https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?id_token=<your-id-token-here>

What's the exception/problem from mVerifier.verify?

Comment: thanks, when i checked my token it was invalid, so problem was on client site. due to some work with workspaces i signed my app with debug keystroke and that was problem. when i signed it with real keystroke everything worked fine.

Comment: @MatkoVonJazvecPetrulak, I am also getting GeneralSecurityException exception on tokenVerifier.verify(token) method. is that same issue of debug keystore?

Comment: @ Bipin Vayalu yes it was issue with debug keystore...anyway do not try to log email adresses on your appengine backend.. i did that for testing, forgot to remove that from my code and after couple of months google blocked my developer account (around 200 000 downloads)...... Thats "google-style" justice

Comment: Is there any reason why the back-end couldn't use this endpoint for verification as well?

Comment: If you are using a full oauth key then use this URL instead: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=    Notice that it is access_token instead of id_token

Answer (score 3):

It's an older question, and I guess you already found an answer. But just in case: Click this [link](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2013/01/verifying-back-end-calls-from-android.html) and scroll down.
Basically it tells you to download and include [this library](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/) and write this piece of code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleIdToken;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleIdTokenVerifier;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory;

public class Checker {

private final List mClientIDs;
private final String mAudience;
private final GoogleIdTokenVerifier mVerifier;
private final JsonFactory mJFactory;
private String mProblem = "Verification failed. (Time-out?)";

public Checker(String[] clientIDs, String audience) {
    mClientIDs = Arrays.asList(clientIDs);
    mAudience = audience;
    NetHttpTransport transport = new NetHttpTransport();
    mJFactory = new GsonFactory();
    mVerifier = new GoogleIdTokenVerifier(transport, mJFactory);
}

public GoogleIdToken.Payload check(String tokenString) {
    GoogleIdToken.Payload payload = null;
    try {
        GoogleIdToken token = GoogleIdToken.parse(mJFactory, tokenString);
        if (mVerifier.verify(token)) {
            GoogleIdToken.Payload tempPayload = token.getPayload();
            if (!tempPayload.getAudience().equals(mAudience))
                mProblem = "Audience mismatch";
            else if (!mClientIDs.contains(tempPayload.getIssuee()))
                mProblem = "Client ID mismatch";
            else
                payload = tempPayload;
        }
    } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
        mProblem = "Security issue: " + e.getLocalizedMessage();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        mProblem = "Network problem: " + e.getLocalizedMessage();
    }
    return payload;
}

public String problem() {
    return mProblem;
}
}
```

Comment: I don't like pulling in that dependency just for GsonFactory.  Any other way?

Comment: @Patrick Long time ago you asked, but in case any one is wondering too, if you are using Jackson, (which I think it comes with this lib) you can use  `JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();`

Comment: what are the dependendent jars req. it gives me error that "It is indirectly referenced from required .class files"

Answer (score 0):

Her is a useful piece of code to check authentication of a token from google. I am using Java EE so it may be slightly different if you are using normal Java:

```
public JsonObject authenticateFromToken(String token) {
       JsonObject jsonst = null;
        JsonReader p = null;
        try {
            p = Json.createReader(new URL("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token="+token).openStream());
            jsonst = (JsonObject) p.read();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return jsonst;
    }
```

After you have the `JsonObject`, you can get info from it like such:

```
jsonObject.getString("user_id");
```

or

```
jsonObject.getString("email");
```

etc...